# Setting color in MVC DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to set a dropdown color based on a model in MVC.

```
public class Viewer
{
    public List<SLI> ls { get; set; }

    public string SelectedReport { get; set; }
    //public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MyReports { get; set; }
    public string PDFLoc { get; set; }
    public List<Status> Stat { get; set; }

}

public class SLI : SelectListItem
{
    public string Color { get; set; }

}
```

I can set the "Color" and pass it to the view.  but I dont know how to create a new DropDownListFor that has the style color:red

I have tried various things like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedReport, new SelectList(Model.ls, "Value", "Text"), new {style = "color: "+ m=>m.ls.Color +"});
```

and in the controller:

```
 public ActionResult Viewer()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        if (S.UserAuthorized())
        {
            Data D = new Data();


            Viewer V=  new Viewer();
            V.ls = D.GetReportsAssignedToUser();
            V.PDFLoc = "";
            V.SelectedReport = "";
            //Get status of reports
            V.Stat = D.GetReportStatuses(V.ls);


            return View(V);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I really dont get the anonymous methods. . .

Answer (score 0):

Modify your class like -

```
public class Viewer
{
    public List<SLI> ls { get; set; }

    public string SelectedReport { get; set; }
    public string PDFLoc { get; set; }
    public List<Status> Stat { get; set; }
    public string DropdownColor { get; set; }
}
```

You can use Jquery like -

```
$("#SelectedReport option").css("color","@Model.DropdownColor");
```

- Where #SelectedReport is the id of the Dropdown.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to create model like this

```
public class DDwithColor
    {

        public List<SelectListItem> SLI { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
```

and your `Viewer` model will be

```
public class Viewer
    {
        public DDwithColor ls { get; set; }
        public string SelectedReport { get; set; }
        public string PDFLoc { get; set; }
        public List<Status> Stat { get; set; }

    }
```

and in `Controller`

```
var viewer = new Viewer();
var ddwithcolor = new DDwithColor();
ddwithcolor.Color = "red";
ddwithcolor.SLI= new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem() { Text = "test", Value = "1" } };
viewer.ls = ddwithcolor;
```

and finally in `view`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedReport, new SelectList(Model.ls.SLI, "Value", "Text"), new{ @style=$"color:{Model.ls.Color}"})
```